# Not changing parameter passed by reference

Tags: go

I have tried to create a file like struct that would comply with io.Writer interface and calculate SHA1 for written data:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "hash"
    "io"
    "os"
)

type WriteWithSHA1 struct {
    originalFile io.Writer
    sha1         hash.Hash
}

func NewWriteWithSHA1(originalFile io.Writer) *WriteWithSHA1 {
    return &WriteWithSHA1{
        originalFile,
        sha1.New(),
    }
}

func (w *WriteWithSHA1) Write(data []byte) (int, error) {
    sha1.Sum(data)
    n, err := w.originalFile.Write(data)
    return n, err
}

func (w *WriteWithSHA1) Sum() []byte {
    return w.sha1.Sum(nil)
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("sha1test.txt")
    check(err)
    defer f.Close()
    w := NewWriteWithSHA1(f)
    _, err = w.Write([]byte("test"))
    check(err)
    s := sha1.New()
    s.Write([]byte("test"))
    fmt.Printf("SHA1: %v\n", hex.EncodeToString(s.Sum(nil)))
}
```

This code returns "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709" - this is SHA1 for "" and not for "test", so it acts as there was no Write operation, i.e. Write does not affect sha1 internal data.

What am I missing here?

Comment: There is no pass-by-reference in Go.

Comment: You're reinventing [io.MultiWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter).

Answer (score 3):

In your `Write`, what do you do with the return value of `sha1.Sum(data)`? It doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Did you intend to invoke `w.sha1.Write` instead?

Comment: Thanks! I knew it some mistake, but I am not experienced in Go, so I assumed it is lack of my knowledge,